# What Type Of Switch Is only on for a second

Tags: led, power, current, switches, relay

I am looking for what type of switch is only only for a split second (1 second max) even when held.

Basically:
Press and hold button-->LED only on for a split second and back off even though I am still holding it. If It is not a 'Switch' then what would I need to do to accomplish this.

EDIT: The Reason I Posted this one is because I'm a beginner, I have No Idea what a Logic Gate is. Is the a component I can just buy?

Comment: If this is to be used with a microcontroller, this would certainly be a job for software, not hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If you are amenable to using a simple circuit you could use a one shot based on a 555 timer chip.  You might also consider an RC circuit.

Comment: 555 Timer Chip, Someting I can Buy? Or Make?

Comment: @display a 555 can be picked up at any electronics store, even radioshack. A 556 is the same but two 555 in one package.